# how to put tabs inside header of the listview?

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I have a listView with an header which contain imageview, bunch of textviews . But now i want to put two tabs at the bottom of that header to change the content of the listview with those two tabs, I am using Sherlockfragments in my app and the whole listview and its header are in one of my fragment .

This is my header of the listview , right now i am using two buttons instead of tabs but i want to replace them with tabs

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/purple_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/userimage_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/loader" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullname_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userimage_profile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="ladygaga"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twittername_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/fullname_profile"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="ladygaga"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/twittername_profile"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="By modifying the URL, dsfhieor fergieirgh erjogw54ijg you can retrieve other variant sizings such as &quot;"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/find_people"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profile_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:src="@drawable/find_people" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/chance_selected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/chances_selected"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:text="Chances(100)"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fav_unselect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/fav_unselected"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:text="Favourites"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/follow_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/find_people"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/userimage_profile"
        android:background="@drawable/follow_reqchance"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Follow"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/req_chance_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/find_people"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/userimage_profile"
        android:background="@drawable/follow_reqchance"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Request Chance"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ive implemented something just like this, I didnt use fragments because they just made things more complicated. Make the tabs buttons and just implement the onclick method to change the listview adapter to show the data you want.

Comment: @shijuB check my edit i want to replace that linearlayout1 with tabhost

Comment: @Clay currently i am using two textviews and upon clicking on these it has to change the content of listview but there are lots of problems coming into it, like when i click 1st textview it shows the data but when i click second textview it shows both the data i.e the data of the first tab and data from the second tab.